# マルチキャストとブロードキャストの違い

Tags: network

私の理解は、下記のとおりなのですが、疑問があります。

- マルチキャストは、複数のクライアントに配信することが目的。
- ブロードキャストは、特定のセグメント内の全ポートに配信することが目的。

**疑問1**
L2ネットワーク（同一セグメント）の場合、マルチキャストもブロードキャストも同様に全ポートに配信される挙動に変わりはない？（IGMP snoopingを使わない場合）

**疑問2**
調べる中で、”フラッディング”という言葉がでてきたのですが、フラッディングはMACアドレスが解決できなかった場合に、全ポートに投げるという意味と理解しました。
ブロードキャストの場合、意図的な全ポート配信なので、フラッディングとは言わない？
同様に、マルチキャストの場合は、フラッディングといってよい？
ブロードキャストもフラッディングといっている記事もあり混乱しています。

Answer (score 0):

前提からおさらいすると、
・マルチキャストは、特定の「アドレス」を指定して通信すること。
・ブロードキャストは、特定の「ネットワーク」を指定して通信すること。
です。

特定のアドレスを指定して通信する都合上、マルチキャストは同一セグメント内の「全て」を
対象としているわけではありません。

例えていうならば、ブロードキャストは〇〇町全域に聞こえる防災放送。
マルチキャストは、〇〇町△△会の会員のみに伝えられる回覧板や会員放送といった感じです。

それを踏まえて、疑問にお答えすると

■疑問1

> （IGMP snoopingを使わない場合）

「IGMP Snoopingを使わない場合」という前提は、やや不完全かと思います。
「マルチキャストグループのメンバーが適切に定義されていない場合」というのが正しいでしょう。

マルチキャストグループのメンバーが適切に定義されていない場合、どのポートがメンバーかを正確に判断出来ない為、全ポートに配信されます。
定義が適切にされている場合は、マルチキャストグループに属するポートのみに配信されます。

※IGMP Snoopingは、スイッチ側が自動的にマルチキャストグループの加入/離脱を判断し、適切な転送を行う為の機能ですが、この機能を用いずに手動でメンバー定義を行うことも可能です。

ブロードキャストは、同一ネットワーク内への一斉配信が前提にありますので、全ポートに配信されます。

■疑問2

> 調べる中で、”フラッディング”という言葉がでてきたのですが、フラッディングはMACアドレスが解決できなかった場合に、全ポートに投げるという意味と理解しました。

スイッチ自身のMACアドレステーブルに記載されていないフレームについては、受け取った誰かがしっかり処理してくれることを期待して全ポートに配信される為、フラッディングが発生します。

> ブロードキャストの場合、意図的な全ポート配信なので、フラッディングとは言わない？

ブロードキャストは一斉配信するのが正しい動作の為、フラッディングではありません。
この場合の全ポート転送は「ブロードキャスティング」と言います。

> 同様に、マルチキャストの場合は、フラッディングといってよい？

マルチキャストまたはユニキャストの場合、先に述べたように適切な定義がされていない場合、全ポートに転送するしかない為、「フラッディング」となります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変わかりやすかったです。理解できました！